# How to get terms of not only the current cat but also of all its children

Tags: terms, count

I'm modding a theme to use parent taxonomy terms instead of all taxonomy terms, now I've been able to only display the parents, but now I've run into a count problem.

Basicly this is the code that has to be changed

```
$_products_in_term = get_objects_in_term( $term->term_id, $taxonomy );
```

This gets all the terms of the current term, which then later is used to do an intercept with and then count. Now how could I mod this code to not only get the terms of the current term but if it has children get the terms of all its children , (will only go 1 deep, not gonna work with grandchildren)

This is the code the full code

```
               foreach ($terms as $term) { 

                // Get count based on current view - uses transients
                $transient_name = 'wc_ln_count_' . md5( sanitize_key($taxonomy) . sanitize_key( $term->term_id ) );

                if ( false === ( $_products_in_term = get_transient( $transient_name ) ) ) {

                //  $_products_in_term = get_objects_in_term( $term->term_id, $taxonomy );

                $args2['child_of'] = $term->term_id;
                $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy , $args2 );
                $term_array=array();
                foreach($terms as $terms){
                $term_array[]= $terms->term_id;
                }

                $_products_in_term = get_objects_in_term( $term_array, $taxonomy ); 

                    set_transient( $transient_name, $_products_in_term );
                }

                $option_is_set = (isset($_chosen_attributes[$taxonomy]) && in_array($term->term_id, $_chosen_attributes[$taxonomy]['terms'])) ; 

                // If this is an AND query, only show options with count > 0
                if ($query_type=='and') {

                    $count = sizeof(array_intersect($_products_in_term, $woocommerce->query->filtered_product_ids));

                    // skip the term for the current archive
                    if ( $current_term == $term->term_id ) continue; 

                    if ($count>0 && $current_term !== $term->term_id ) $found = true;

                    if ($count==0 && !$option_is_set) continue;

                // If this is an OR query, show all options so search can be expanded
                } else { 

                    // skip the term for the current archive
                    if ( $current_term == $term->term_id ) continue;

                    $count = sizeof(array_intersect($_products_in_term, $woocommerce->query->unfiltered_product_ids));

                    if ($count>0) $found = true;

                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$terms = get_term_children( $term->term_id , $taxonomy );
$term_array=array();
foreach($terms as $terms){
  $term_array[]= $terms;
}

$_products_in_term = get_objects_in_term( $term_array, $taxonomy );
```

Comment: Doesnt work, should be very close to solution tho, could you check if you maybe made an error?, added full code and your replacement.

Comment: $args['child_of'] = $term->term_id; 

will this get the childs of the terms? Seems kinda of wierd?

Comment: OKee tested some more, problem is it gets the id of all the terms not just the terms of the current term and its children. You fill that first args with parents of the term not? 'child_of' seems to give IDs of its parent? Should be giving Id's of its children

Comment: @Bram Have updated my answer, have tested this and this should work now...

Comment: Current code is functional thanks. Variable names are very confusing though. `foreach($terms as $terms)` is a crime against semantics, should be `foreach($terms as $child_term_id)`. It would be much clearer like that :)